# Combine minted and tcolorbox

Tags: environments, minted, tcolorbox

I have the idea to combine `minted` with `tcolorbox`.

At first, I have created my own minted environments:

```
\newminted[mycsharp]{csharp}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myjson]{js}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myxml]{xml}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myshell]{shell-session}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[mycode]{text}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
```

With them I do highlight my code:

```
\begin{myshell}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
\end{myshell}
\captionof{listing}{Load network configuration with vi}
```

So I get the following:
[image: Example output]

Now I want to have a nice frame around. Since minted is not so powerful here, I want to use tcolorbox, so I did this:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{myshell}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
\end{myshell}
\end{tcolorbox}
\captionof{listing}{Load network configuration with vi}
```

And I get this one here:

[image: Example #2]

This is nice, but not what I want. After looking in the package documentation of `tcolorbox` I found out that it supports titles:

[image: Exmaple #3]

It's getting better. After reading some more, `tcolorbox` also has supported for auto numbered titles and a "list of"-support. Unfortunately the provided examples in the documentation do not work, but that's another question.

Okay, now. What do I want to have?

I want to have something like:

```
\begin{listingsbox}{myshell}{A nice title}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
\end{listingsbox}
```

to get the following output:

[image: Final example]

Unfortunately I'm not able to write this by self. I tried it using the `\newenvironment` macro, but after googeling, it is not easy to integrate minted into a new environment.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You've mentioned problems with 'auto numbered titles' and 'list of'. I used both of them in my answer for demonstration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had some trouble setting up `minted` with pygments on Windows, but now it seems to run. So, this is my first `minted` text - so, please, forgive me, if I'm doing some nonsense here. Nevertheless, I have found something which may be a ground to build on. The following code uses not exactly your syntax, but creates a `myshellbox` instead.
Basically, I use the `listings` features of `tcolorbox` and trick `minted` in at some point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{minted language/.store in=\kvtcb@minted@language}

\def\tcbuselistinglisting{%
  \toks@=\expandafter{\kvtcb@listingoptions}%
  \edef\tcb@temp{\noexpand\inputminted[\the\toks@]}%
  \tcb@temp{\kvtcb@minted@language}{\kvtcb@listingfile}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section,
  list inside=mypyg]{myshellbox}[2][]{%
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #2},
  list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2},
  minted language=shell-session,
  listing options={tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize},
  listing only,
  enhanced,colframe=red!50!black,drop fuzzy shadow,
  #1}

\begin{myshellbox}{Load network configuration with vi}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
\end{myshellbox}

\begin{myshellbox}{Something else}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/something
\end{myshellbox}

\tcblistof{mypyg}{My Listings}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** It should me mentioned that the created `myshellbox` environment takes an optional parameter, where further options can be put in, e.g. `minted language=<something>` or `listing option=<something>`.

**EDIT:** The second solution is a combination of my first solution with Marco Daniel's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted[mycsharp]{csharp}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myjson]{js}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myxml]{xml}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myshell]{shell-session}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[mycode]{text}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,
  list inside=mypyg]{mintedbox}[2][]{%
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #2},
  list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2},
  enhanced,colframe=red!50!black,drop fuzzy shadow,#1}

\newenvironment{listingsbox}[3][]
 {%
   \def\listingsboxenvironment{#2}%save the environments
   \VerbatimEnvironment%
   \begin{mintedbox}[#1]{#3}%
     \begin{\listingsboxenvironment}}%
 {%
  \end{\listingsboxenvironment}%
  \end{mintedbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{listingsbox}{myshell}{A nice title}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
\end{listingsbox}

\begin{listingsbox}{myshell}{Something else}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/something
\end{listingsbox}

\begin{listingsbox}{myxml}{XML box}
<hello>World</hello>
\end{listingsbox}

\tcblistof{mypyg}{My Listings}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** Newer versions of `tcolorbox` have integrated support for `minted`. Therefore, a more elegant solution with the same output is possible now. I also added a macro `\mynewminted` which creates a style for `tcolorbox` plus an equally named `minted` environment, if this is needed somewhere else.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many,minted]{tcolorbox}% version 3.03 or better

\newcommand{\mynewminted}[3]{%
  \newminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
  \tcbset{myminted/#1/.style={minted language=#2,minted options={#3}}}}

\mynewminted{mycsharp}{csharp}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\mynewminted{myjson}{js}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\mynewminted{myxml}{xml}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\mynewminted{myshell}{shell-session}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\mynewminted{mycode}{text}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section,
  list inside=mypyg]{listingsbox}[3][]{%
  listing only,title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #3},
  list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#3},
  enhanced,colframe=red!50!black,drop fuzzy shadow,myminted/#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{listingsbox}{myshell}{A nice title}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
\end{listingsbox}

\begin{listingsbox}{myshell}{Something else}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/something
\end{listingsbox}

\begin{listingsbox}{myxml}{XML box}
<hello>World</hello>
\end{listingsbox}

\tcblistof{mypyg}{My Listings}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently I get `Unknown option 'most' for package 'tcolorbox'`. I have a miktex 2.9 running. I'm trying to reinstall it. Maybe something went wrong.

Comment: Okay, I had an older version of the package installed. I updated it and get following errors: `Missing number, treated as zero \newtcblisting[a` `You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode \newtcblisting[a`. Unfortunately I get this error too, when I try to compile your example :/

Comment: Are you sure to have tcolorbox 2.40? Your logfile should contain a line `Package: tcolorbox 2013/07/15 version 2.40 text color boxes`.

Comment: Strange. At first I had 2.30, after updating with miktex, it installed 2.33 and now it shows a message box `No updates available`. It's update mirror's version is from 9. July 2013 - maybe they are outdated? http://miktex.org/packages/tcolorbox

Comment: Okay, I updated the package manually and it's working! The best would be to combine your solution with Marco Daniel's one. I like the idea to write `\begin{listingbox}{myshell}{Title}` :)

Comment: @Raubi Yes, it is possible to combine the solutions. I've updated my answer with such a combination :-)

Comment: This is outstanding! I wish I could upvote more than once :)

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing, but could I ask you for one more thing? Well, actually two things: Sometimes I need to place a footmark within the title. Since the title is showed in the `listof` it does not work. And a labelling support would be nice too. I'm thinking of something like `\begin{listingsbox}[title={I'm a nice title\footmarknote!}, label={lst:mycode}, language={myshell}, listofentry={I'm such a nice title!}]{mycode goes here...}`. I haven't done LaTeX programming before and currently I'm trying to do this by myself using the `xkeyval` package. The learning cure is quite steep :D

Comment: @Raubi I've modified my answer. `listingsbox` is now able to take options which are passed to the underlying `tcolorbox`. Therefore, you can use `\begin{listingsbox}[label={lst:mycode}, after title={\footmarknote},...]{mintenv}{title}`. For '...' you may fill anything `tcolorbox` offers as options. If you have specific problem, you should ask a new question since comments don't have a lot of room.

Comment: Yep, you are right, but I think it's currently all working as I want. Thank you very much, Thomas! You saved me hours :-)

Comment: Since some updates this does not work anymore, gettings errors like: `Use of \\smash doesn't match its definition ...`, `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup ...`. Unfortunately I don't know, which updates causes the problem

Comment: Hm... I do not get any error. My system is a week old. I cannot update MikTeX today, because of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179454/miktex-problem-after-last-update . Nevertheless, I updated my answer with a new solution you could try. But I have no idea where the `\smash` error may come from (and I cannot reproduce the error).

Comment: @Raubi Even after updating today, I do not get any errors ...

Comment: Currently the MikTeX package repository is down. I'm going to try this, after it is available again. Maybe I get those errors because I'm using some other hacks for minted (Unicode, line breaking).

Comment: I updated my packages and tried out your example, which works well. I tried to update my document with all the needed changes and can't get it to work. I saw, that I'm using srcreprt as document class. Would be so kind and try to change it in your example and see if it works (or it's a fault of my local miktex installation)? If I do it with your examples pdflatex compiles forever

Comment: @Raubi I think I found the problem with `scrreprt`. The `\numberline` has to be replaced by `\protect\numberline`. I've updated my example above and it works with `scrreprt` now.

Comment: Awesome! I hope someday I can stand you are beer for your help!

Comment: TIL trying to use the language signifyer `bash` results in only incorrect syntax highlighting - you have to instead use `shell-session`. I guess I should RTFD, but that's just... weird...

Answer (score 4):

Here a first suggestion with your requirements. The new environment `listingsbox` has two mandatory arguments whereby the first argument is a predefined minted environment and the second argument is the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted[mycsharp]{csharp}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myjson]{js}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myxml]{xml}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myshell]{shell-session}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[mycode]{text}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}

\tcbset{
texexp/.style={colframe=red!50!yellow!50!black, colback=red!50!yellow!5!white,
coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!white,
fonttitle=\small\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small}, example/.style 2 args={texexp,
title={Example \refstepcounter{texexp}\label{#2}\thetexexp: #1}},
}
\newenvironment{listingsbox}[2]
 {% 
  \def\listingsboxenvironment{#1}%save the environments
  \captionsetup{skip=0pt,font={color=white}}%
  \VerbatimEnvironment%
   \begin{tcolorbox}[title=\captionof{listing}{#2}]%
    \begin{\listingsboxenvironment}}%
 {%
  \end{\listingsboxenvironment}%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{listingsbox}{myshell}{A nice title}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
\end{listingsbox}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You told me once before to consider `minted` ;-) After some first steps, it looks like it could be possible to have a kind of *drop in* replacement for `listings` in my package. Your solution here seems not to need an auxiliary file which is quite nice.