# Cross referencing tcolorbox with cleveref-package

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, tcolorbox

Thanks to Thomas F. Sturm (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124688/15907), I have a little environment for creating nice-looking source code in LaTeX.

I started my environment with this here:

```
\begin{listingsbox}[label={lst:agent:logstash:configuration}]{mycode}{Konfiguration von LogStash auf Agent}
```

(The part in the square brackets are the same commands as for tcolorbox.)

And I have my own little ref command:

```
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{see \cref{#1} \nameref{#1} \vpageref{#1}}
```

So I get something like: "see figure 3.1: How to chuck wood on page 31", which is really nice.

If I do this with the label of the tcolorbox:

```
\myref{lst:agent:logstash:configuration}
```

I get: "see ?? 3.1: Konfiguration von LogStash on page 31".

As you can see, `cleveref` is not able to provide a correct name here.
I know I can change this when defining it with `\crefname{<type>}{<singular>}{<plural>}` but I can not figure out which type I have to provide.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type you are looking for is `tcb@cnt@mintedbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newminted[mycsharp]{csharp}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myjson]{js}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myxml]{xml}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[myshell]{shell-session}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}
\newminted[mycode]{text}{tabsize=2,fontsize=\footnotesize}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,
  list inside=mypyg]{mintedbox}[2][]{%
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #2},
  list entry={\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2},
  enhanced,colframe=red!50!black,drop fuzzy shadow,#1}

\newenvironment{listingsbox}[3][]
 {%
   \def\listingsboxenvironment{#2}%save the environments
   \VerbatimEnvironment%
   \begin{mintedbox}[#1]{#3}%
     \begin{\listingsboxenvironment}}%
 {%
  \end{\listingsboxenvironment}%
  \end{mintedbox}%
}

\makeatletter
\crefname{tcb@cnt@mintedbox}{minted listing}{minted listings}
\Crefname{tcb@cnt@mintedbox}{Minted listing}{Minted listings}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\Cref{lst:agent:logstash:configuration} and \cref{lst:agent:logstash:configuration}.
\Cref{lst:agent:logstash:configuration,lst:test} and \cref{lst:agent:logstash:configuration,lst:test}.

\begin{listingsbox}[label={lst:agent:logstash:configuration}]{myshell}{A nice title}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
\end{listingsbox}

\begin{listingsbox}[label={lst:test}]{myshell}{Something else}
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/something
\end{listingsbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The type can be easily obtained examining the output console; if you process my code without the `\crefname`, `\Crefname` lines, you will get several warnings like this one:

```
LaTeX Warning: cref  reference format for label type `tcb@cnt@mintedbox' undefi
ned on input line 33.
```

And the messages show the type that has to be used in `\crefname`.

Comment: Just a little question, maybe it's easy, so you can update your answer, otherwise I would open a new question: As you can see, I'm using `\nameref` in my `\myref` marco. But it outputs the section title instead the title of the listing. Do you have any idea here?

Comment: @Raubi I think it's better to open a new question; please provide in that question a complete little example code (like the one I used in my answer here) showing your current settings.