# Is there a way to prepend something on every line using tcolorbox and minted?

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, code

The [tcolorbox manual](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) shows a nice example of prepending a command prompt on every line of a shell input (page 317), but it apparently only works for the `listings` library. Is there a similar option for the `minted` library? I searched through the manual for `minted`, but the only option I found that might offer this option was the `formatcom` option… but I don't think that is going to work.

For the record, I would be fine with the output in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125029), but I

1. can't figure out how to format this inside the definition for a `\newtcblisting` (color, font weight, etc.), and
2. don't want to have to include my prompt info on every line throughout my file.

My current MWE is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{bashinput}[1][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=bash,
  minted options={
    fontsize=\small,
    breaklines,
    autogobble,
    numbersep=2mm},
  listing only,
  ,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{bashinput}
user ~$ vi /etc/sysconfig/network
user ~$ grep Dipole file-name -A1 | tail -n1 | awk '\{print \$8\}'
\end{bashinput}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I could just add a line after `listing only,` containing something like `every listing line={\textcolor{red}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries  ~$}}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How insert a character at the begin of every line from a source code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340232/how-insert-a-character-at-the-begin-of-every-line-from-a-source-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340239/170958), using the `formatcom` option of the [`minted`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

% < ADDED CODE >
\newcommand{\BashFancyFormatLine}{%
  \def\FancyVerbFormatLine##1{\textcolor{red}{\small\$}\ ##1}%
}
% </ADDED CODE >

\newtcblisting{bashinput}[1][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=bash,
  minted options={
    fontsize=\small,
    breaklines,
    autogobble,
    numbersep=2mm,
    formatcom=\BashFancyFormatLine}, % ADDED LINE
  listing only,
  ,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{bashinput}
some text
\end{bashinput}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ugh, can't believe I missed that answer. This is perfect, thank you!