# MikTeX problem after last update

Tags: miktex

After my last update on May 20th 2014, the Miktex Update Wizard give me this error:

```
The `.tmp` file could not be parsed.
```

Details:

```
C:\User\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\mik13840\pstool.tmp
```

I think that `pstool.tmp` is the problem. I tried to delete the package, but the problem still appear. I cannot find the folder `mik13840` and each time I run the update, the number after "mik" change.

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your local tpm files are in your miktex tree in tpm/packages. If you try to open pstool.tpm with an xml editor like xml notepad it will complain about "line 2 position 1795". In this position there is an `&` between the names. Deleting the `&` will enable you to use the package manager. But not the update manager as it it still will try to parse the online tpm. So make a bug report at the miktex site so that the tpm can be repaired.

Comment: I now made a bug report. https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2323/

Comment: I haven't this file on my PC. Where I can find it? A "google search" don't help me :-(

Comment: @texusers123456 You can find it in C:\Program Files\Miktex 2.9\tpm\packages\pstool.tpm. I also have this update problem. The error message poped-up is telling you the cached pstool from remote server cannot be parsed. As Ulrike mentioned, it contains illegal sign & there.

Comment: i think this is fixed.

Comment: @Ali How can I check whether this kind bug is fixed or not? Where is the source? It is weird that only few guys care about this bug. PS: I green hand on MikteX.

Comment: I was having a problem similar to what you have mentioned. I have tried today again, it was working. I assume not everybody is updating miktex as occasional as we do.

Answer (score 2):

The concrete problem has been resolved by an update. But here some background information regarding `tpm` files and what one can do if one get the error `The .tmp file could not be parsed.`

`tpm`-files contain information about a package: version number, included files, where they should be installed etc. `tpm`-files are `xml`-files. And if they contain syntax errors then the parsing of the `xml` can fail, like the "parsing" of a tex-file can fail. Here a faulty `&` in a name was the problem.

`tpm`-files exist in two places: After the miktex installation there is a local copy of all existing `tpm` in the main texmf tree in `tpm\packages`. The package manager use this `tpm` to show you e.g. the content of a package (right click ->properties).

These local files are updated when you synchronize. 
If such a file is faulty after the synchronization you can open it with an `xml`-editor and correct it. This should at least allow you to use the package manager (as long as you don't try to install the faulty package).

There are also online `tpm` files. These are used by the update manager. They must be repaired by the miktex maintainer, so one should make a bug report like this https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2323/.