# article.cls not found after last update

Tags: miktex

Latex work fine till I do the last update today.

When compiling a text, document, I have an error :

> article.cls not found

Samething for book and report class.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you compile mid-update?

Comment: What do you mean by mid-update

Comment: While MiKTeX is updating, if you compile, the hash file is being updated, which will make *nothing* work. Perhaps, rerun the Refresh FNDB from the MiKTeX Package Manager menu and try again after it is complete.

Comment: I Refresh FNDB and still not work. I did not compile during the update.

Comment: My magic 8-ball says: I don't know; we cannot reproduce; perhaps re-install MiKTeX?

Comment: extracting files from latex-base.tar.lzma...
pdflatex.EXE: Permission denied: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\doc/latex/base/00readme.txt
pdflatex.EXE: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\doc/latex/base/00readme.txt
======================================================================

! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:

Comment: HWerner, have you done the last update (May 21th)

Comment: Nope. I run on TeX Live (also on Windows).

Comment: Any idea please ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, therefore I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I suppose that the update fails with setting the wrong read/write permissions.

Comment: Herbert, Do you know how to fix that ? Thanks.

Comment: I am a Linux user. I have no idea how to fix it with windows. Did you run the update on Windows as user or administrator?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Open miktex settings go to the tab root, check "show miktex maintained roots". Is your main installation root in the list?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a re-install resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly the same: it just happened to me but it did not seem to be a problem with a .tpm file. Actually, for some  reason, last update deleted the `ltxbase` package. So it was highly unlikely you'd be able to compile whatever.

However, `ltxbase.tar.lzma` still exists in MiKTeX repository. What I did was to download it from, say, [Dante](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/). Then I untar-lzma'ed the file (7-zip can do it), resulting in a `texmf` directory. All I had to do was to copy the contents of this directory at the root of `MiKTeX 2.9` and refresh the FNDB via `MiKTeX Settings`.

Comment: Did you make a bug report?

Comment: Well, I do not know how to do it. I'll try to find out today.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: bug report made today.

Comment: You are a bit late. The problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is an error in miktex, is equal to the error given in [MikTeX problem after last update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179454/miktex-problem-after-last-update).

happens to me and it was the same for the update.

Comment: If it's the same, then we can close it as a duplicate, right?

Comment: @Werner: It doesn't sound as the same error. The error yesterday affected the package manager and gave a parsing error. It didn't affected the file search.