# Error file.cls not found after update

Tags: errors, installing, mactex

I recently updated my tex distribution on mac to try and get use of a font in texlive-extra (I used macports). However, this didn't work and led to errors. As a result I decided to do a clean install following the instructions here: http://www.tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html moving usr/local/texlive and usr/local/texmf to trash, along with the GUI applications.

When I did a clean install from mactex here: http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html all seemed to go fine, but when I try and compile using a makefile that was fine before I get the result:

```
LaTeX Error: File `book.cls' not found.
```

(same for articles, reports, etc.)

If I run macports with

```
sudo port install texlive texlive-latex-extra
```

I get the result:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for texlive
--->  Cleaning texlive
--->  Computing dependencies for texlive-latex-extra
--->  Cleaning texlive-latex-extra
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
```

And nothing happens.

If someone could help me out with fixing this, or the correct way to do a clean install I would be grateful.

I came across a similar issue here: [article.cls not found after last update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179665/article-cls-not-found-after-last-update) but it was closed without a clear answer.

Thanks

Comment: Mactex and the stuff from macports are not the same and probably should not be used together. My guess is that you have two latex installations and your Mac gets confused

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that. I've run 'sudo port uninstall texlive texlive-latex-extra' but the problem is still persisting.

Comment: Uninstailling is probably not enough, and LaTeX on the mac is a heap of shortcuts that also needs cleaning. In a terminal what does `which pdflatex` return? What does `kpsewhich article.cls` say?

Comment: which pdflatex returns /opt/local/bin/pdflatex
kpsewhich article.cls returns nothing

Comment: Have you tried `sudo texhash`? To rebuild the filename database

Comment: Yes, the result I got was as follows:

    `texhash: Updating /opt/local/etc/texmf/ls-R...`  
    `texhash: Updating /opt/local/var/db/texmf/ls-R...`  
    `texhash: Done.`

But when I try to compile as I normally would I still get File `article.cls' not found.

Comment: Then I don't know what is wrong with your installation. I'd probably try to uninstall all LaTeX related and then install MacTeX again. Just reinstalling MacTeX "could" work, but I'm not sure. Things can get really messed up when you mix installations.

Comment: OK, thanks for trying to help. When you say uninstall all LaTeX related, what is the best way to do that? Should I just look around for anything with TeX in the filename and move to trash?

Comment: I do not use Mac, so I cannot help you there.

Comment: I tried the above and a new install of MacTeX, and I now have the error `warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /opt/local/etc/texmf.` If that indicates anything further. Compilation now works and generates a pdf file, but all of my citations (using natbib) throw errors and appear as ? in the pdf so its still not fixed yet.

Comment: Update: I have taken the `texmf.cnf` file located at `usr/local/texlive/2017/` and copied it to `opt/local/etc/texmf/` and no longer get the kpathsea error. The error with natbib is still there however.

Comment: Ohh, then I probably know what is going on, your PATH settings are wrong. All MacTeX lives in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/`, so things refering to `/opt/local/etc/texmf/`might be completely wrong. What does `echo $PATH` say in a terminal

Comment: `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin`

Comment: and `which pdflatex`?

Comment: `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`

Comment: `which kpsewhich`?

Comment: `/opt/local/bin/kpsewhich`

Comment: `ls -l  /Library/Te‌​X/texbin`

Comment: `ls: /Library/Te‌​X/texbin: No such file or directory`

Comment: kpsewhich should have been from `texlive/2017/...`

Comment: @FluidFox *Don't install* the MacPorts version of TeX Live under any circumstance. Uninstall it to begin with, then install MacTeX.

Comment: OK, how do I get it to look there instead?

Comment: So you still have stuff around from the old installations. I do not remember how MacTeX sets things up (it is done via short cuts)

Comment: @egreg I ran `sudo port uninstall texlive texlive-latex-extra` before reinstalling MacTeX

Comment: You probably have a lot more texlive stuff, can port list what it has installed?

Comment: @FluidFox If `which kpsewhich` still returns `/opt/local/bin/kpsewhich` then you're in trouble. What's the output of `ls -l /opt/local/bin/kpsewhich`?

Comment: yes, I get this for `port installed`:

Comment: `texlive-basic @44435_0+doc (active)
  texlive-bin @2017_1+x11 (active)
  texlive-bin-extra @44432_0+doc (active)
  texlive-common @2017.1_0 (active)
  texlive-context @44436_0+doc (active)
  texlive-fonts-extra @44409_0+doc (active)
  texlive-fonts-recommended @42428_0+doc (active)
  texlive-fontutils @44166_0+doc (active)
  texlive-lang-czechslovak @44347_0+doc (active)`

Plus more

Comment: for `ls -l /Library/Te‌​X/texbin` I now get `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  29 13 Sep 11:02 /Library/TeX/texbin -> Distributions/Programs/texbin`

Comment: @egreg I get `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  45 20 Jun 08:46 /opt/local/bin/kpsewhich -> /opt/local/libexec/texlive/binaries/kpsewhich` for `ls -l /opt/local/bin/kpsewhich`

Comment: You'll probably need to uninstall all that mac posts know about TeXLive. Then hopefully it should clean up after it self and you can work with MacTeX.

Comment: I think that `sudo port uninstall 'texlive*'` is called for here. Also, remove anything tex-related that you installed under `/opt/local` by hand.

Comment: For `sudo port uninstall 'texlive*'` I get the following warning: `The following ports will break: pdfjam @2.08_0`

Comment: is `pdfjam`, something you use?

Comment: It probably won't *actually* break. Try `sudo port uninstall --force 'texlive*'`. As soon as you have a working MacTeX installed, `pdfjam` will likely work again.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I also have `latexmk`, `latexdiff`, `detex`, and `ghostscript` listed under macports installed. Should these go too? Having proceeded with removing all the texlive items in macports and anything I placed manually in /opt/local/etc/ I can compile and produce pdfs, but still have issues with natbib. Should I try reinstalling MacTeX at this point?

Comment: Could be that some other port needs pdfjam. You can ask nicely, using `port dependents pdfjam`.

Comment: no other dependants so I proceeded. Should I also get rid of `latexmk`, `latexdiff`, `detex`, and `ghostscript`? and try to install MacTeX again?

Comment: pdfjam is just a frontend to the `pdfpages` package, so it only needs latex to be installed

Comment: We have a similar issue on Linux (for example Ubuntu). When we install TUG TeXLive (instead of the Ubuntu equivalent of mac ports), we'll need to tell the package manager that we have installed something similar to some of its own packages. Perhaps there exists something similar for mac ports. But again if pdfjam is not something you use, then uninstall that as well

Comment: OK, I proceeded and removed it. Should I also remove `latexmk`, `latexdiff`, `detex`, and `ghostscript`? I will then run the install package from MacTeX again and see what happens.

Comment: Not sure if ghostscript is a part of mactex, but the others are (as you can see splitting up into these smaller pieces makes everything a lot more confusing). Ghostscript should not depend on texlive.

Comment: OK, I haven't removed those packages listed above yet, but re-ran the MacTeX install package, and now compilation seems to run fine and natbib no longer throws problems. Is there a check I can run to see if things seem back in the correct places (e.g. `which pdflatex` or `ls -l /Library/Te‌​X/texbin`)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65718/discussion-on-question-by-fluidfox-error-file-cls-not-found-after-update).