# z-index , tcolorbox , tikz and overlays

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, overlays

The code below does a rather code job except that it uses opacity instead of z-index such as to have a soft red background. In the following screenshot you can see that the frame is upon the `tcolorbox` and the `minted` highlighted code.

[image]

I would like to draw my frame between the `tcolorbox` and the `minted` highlighted code. Is there a way to do that ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[skins, many, minted, breakable, hooks]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit}

\makeatletter

% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/3954
\newcommand\myframe[5][-1ex]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,pin distance=0cm]{
        \draw[draw=#4,line width=1pt,fill=#4!20,rectangle,rounded corners, opacity=#5]
        ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (-1ex,2ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (1ex,#1) $ );
        \draw[draw=#4,line width=1pt,rectangle,rounded corners, opacity=1]
        ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (-1ex,2ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (1ex,#1) $ );
    }
}

% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124688/6880
\newcommand{\mynewminted}[3]{%
    \newminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
    \tcbset{myminted/#1/.style = {
        minted language = #2, 
        minted options  = {#3}
    }}
}

\newcommand{\create@new@coding@env@title}[4]{%
    \mynewminted{for-coding-#1}{python}{escapeinside=||}
    \newtcblisting[]{coding-#1}[2][1]{%
        listing only,
        width        = ##1\linewidth,
        title        = ##2,
        myminted/for-coding-python,
    }
}

\create@new@coding@env@title{python}{\Large\faPython}{2mm}{1.8mm}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Hack that works}

\begin{coding-python}{Basic loop
Python}
|\tikzmark{topleft}|def oneloop(n):            
    for i in range(n):
        print(i**2)   |\tikzmark{downright}|

print(oneloop(n))
\end{coding-python}

\myframe{topleft}{downright}{red}{0.2}



\section{Indeed the frame is upon !}

\begin{coding-python}{Basic loop
Python}
|\tikzmark{topleftbis}|def oneloop(n):            
    for i in range(n):
        print(i**2)   |\tikzmark{downrightbis}|

print(oneloop(n))
\end{coding-python}

\myframe{topleftbis}{downrightbis}{red}{1}



\section{Here the frame is under !}

\myframe[-15ex]{topleftter}{downrightter}{red}{1}

\begin{coding-python}{Basic loop
Python}
|\tikzmark{topleftter}|def oneloop(n):            
    for i in range(n):
        print(i**2)   |\tikzmark{downrightter}|

print(oneloop(n))
\end{coding-python}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: @AndréC Hello. I have updated my question to clarify the problem I am facing to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved rather easily. Draw the box *before* the code. Now you may say: "Wait, before the code? But then the `tikzmark`s are not yet set.". This is true, but `tikzmark` works by writing stuff to the aux file, which gets read at the very beginning. In order to avoid annoying error messages in the first run I wrap the code that draws the frame into `\@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#2}}{}{<code>}`, where `#2` is the name of the mark. This is `tikzmark`s builtin way to check whether or not a mark exists. Clearly, this trick has many more seemingly "causality-violating" applications that can be used to draw *anything* as an "underlay".

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[skins, many, minted, breakable, hooks]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit}

\makeatletter

% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/3954
\newcommand\myframe[4][-1ex]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,pin distance=0cm]{
        \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#2}}{%
        %    
        }{%
        \draw[draw=#4,line width=1pt,fill=#4!20,rectangle,rounded corners]
        ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (-1ex,2ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (1ex,#1) $ );
        \draw[draw=#4,line width=1pt,rectangle,rounded corners, opacity=1]
        ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (-1ex,2ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (1ex,#1) $ );
        }
    }% <-added
}

% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124688/6880
\newcommand{\mynewminted}[3]{%
    \newminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
    \tcbset{myminted/#1/.style = {
        minted language = #2, 
        minted options  = {#3}
    }}
}

\newcommand{\create@new@coding@env@title}[4]{%
    \mynewminted{for-coding-#1}{python}{escapeinside=||}
    \newtcblisting[]{coding-#1}[2][1]{%
        listing only,
        width        = ##1\linewidth,
        title        = ##2,
        myminted/for-coding-python,
    }
}

\create@new@coding@env@title{python}{\Large\faPython}{2mm}{1.8mm}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{tikzmark underlay}

\begin{coding-python}{Basic loop
Python}
|\myframe{topleft}{downright}{red}\tikzmark{topleft}|def oneloop(n):            
    for i in range(n):
        print(i**2)   |\tikzmark{downright}|

print(oneloop(n))
\end{coding-python}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path (pic cs:topleft) coordinate (aux);
\draw[orange] (aux|-current page.north)
-- (aux|-current page.south);
\end{tikzpicture}


How does a \verb|tikzmark| underlay work?
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Put the \verb|\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{...}| stuff \emph{before} the text/code/whatever which you wish to
annotate (but on the same page).
 \item Inside the \verb|\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{...}|| wrap the pieces that use the \verb|tikzmark|s into 
  \begin{verbatim}
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#2}}{}{
   <code>}
  \end{verbatim} 
  Here, \verb|<code>| are these pieces.
\end{enumerate}
Since the coordinates of the \verb|tikzmark|s get written to the \verb|aux|
file, they are ``known'' before the compiler goes (in the second run) through
the \LaTeX\ code that defines them.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The orange line is just to guide the eye.

Just for the records: I found the first version of the question very clear and well written.

**ADDENDUM**: Some other applications of the `tikzmark` "underly" trick: an environment that does the check.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{pendingtikzmark}[1]{\@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{%
        %    
        }{\BODY}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{pendingtikzmark}{A}
\fill[red] ([yshift=-0.1ex]pic cs:A) rectangle ([yshift=2ex]pic cs:B);
\end{pendingtikzmark}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\tikzmark{A}A & B\tikzmark{B}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in this case you could achieve the same effect with `atbegshi` (or `eso-pic`), i.e. by putting the overlay picture in a hook that moves it to the beginning of the shipout, but this might be less efforts. In any case, for the `tcolorbox` situation above `atbegshi` will not save the day.

Comment: I have tried your solution but there is a little problem. The text in frame is indented a little to the right.

Comment: @projetmbc Yes, you are right. Good catch! There was a spurious space caused by `\myframe`. I removed it by adding a `%`, and added an orange line to show that it works now.

Comment: Thanks. I should be more suspicious about the spurious.

Comment: @projetmbc You're welcome! I actually really like this question a lot.

Comment: @projetmbc I added a version of this to [your other recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512016/194703). Clearly, there is a lot of room for improvement in this addendum, yet it shows how to use Ti*k*Z coordinates in a "causality violating" way: just use `\path (<coordinate>) node{\tikzmark{<name of mark>}};`. Surely one could modify the Ti*k*Z coordinates and nodes in such a way that they write their definition to the aux file, but this would be a major surgery and easily lead to confusion so I did not attempt doing that.

Comment: Thanks. I take look at this now.